# Understanding MATLAB class properties

Tags: matlab, matlab-class

Considering [this example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/expressions-in-class-definitions.html#bshec04) from the MATLAB Help.

This example, besides having syntax problems, does not seams to work for me. I don't know if is a version issue, I'm using R2013a.

```
classdef MyClass
   properties (Constant = true)
      X = pi/180;
   end
   properties
      PropA = sin(X*MyClass.getAngle([1 0],[0 1]);
   end

   methods (Static = true)
      function r = getAngle(vx,vy)

      end
   end
end
```

It says

> Undefined function or variable 'X'. Error in MyClass (line 1)
>   classdef MyClass

I can fix it by adding `MyClass.X`, but I don't know if this was the purpose.

Comment: You should [report](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/bugreports) this as a documentation bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[That MathWorks example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/expressions-in-class-definitions.html#bshec04) is all messed up.  The intention was probably to have it written like this:

```
classdef MyClass
    properties (Constant = true)
        Deg2Rad = pi/180;
    end
    properties
        PropA = sin(MyClass.Deg2Rad*MyClass.getAngle([1 0],[0 1]));
    end

    methods (Static = true)
        function r = getAngle(vx,vy)
            r = atan2(vy,vx)/MyClass.Deg2Rad;
        end
    end
end
```

I guess the point is to demonstrate a static method and constant property:

```
>> MyClass.getAngle(1,sqrt(3))
ans =
   60.0000
>> MyClass.getAngle(sqrt(3),1)
ans =
   30.0000
>> MyClass.getAngle(0,1)
ans =
    90
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping that there was a similar syntax to C++, where you  don't have to prepend MyClass. all over the place.

Comment: You should [report](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/bugreports) this as a documentation bug.